# How to validate multi step form jquery Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with multi step form with php, I have array `$rec` where i am getting all
questions ( from database/dynamic).

I want to validate those fields whose `key` is `mandatory` and value is `1` (coming from array($rec)).

I want "next" page/question shouldn't display until I fill first question.

Here is my html code

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Nps/FormAdd'); ?>" method="post">
                
                <?php //echo "<pre>"; print_R($keyslug);?>
                <input type="hidden" name="mobile_no" value="<?php echo $keyslug['mobileNo']; ?>">
                 <input type="hidden" name="contact_mapping_id" value="<?php echo $keyslug['id']; ?>">
                <?php $i="1"; 
                $lastElement = end($rec);
                $i="1";
                foreach($rec as $key => $records)
                        { 
<div class="card" id="<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>" >
    <?php if($records['type']=="range" )
                        {
                        ?>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="chart-scale develop-rating">
                                    <?php $j=$records['start_range'];
                                    $max= $records['end_range'];
                                    for($i=$j;$i<=$max; $i++) {
                                    ?>
                                        <button id="rating" attr-hide-div="<?php if($i <= $records['min_value']) { echo $records['max_show_ques_id']; } else { echo $records['show_ques_id']; }?>" 
                                        attr-show-div="<?php if($i <= $records['min_value']) { echo $records['show_ques_id']; } else { echo $records['max_show_ques_id']; }?>"attr-value="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn rating-button-click  btn-scale btn-scale-asc-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $i; ?>
                                        </button>
                                        
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <input type="hidden" id='ques_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>' class="input-develop all-mandatory-check" attr-required="<?php echo $records['mandatory']; ?>" <?php if($records['IsRatingQuestion']=="1") { ?> name='rangeR_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>' <?php } else { ?> name='ques_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>' <?php } ?> value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php 
                        }
                        elseif($records['type']=="check_box")
                            {
                        ?>
                            <div class="form-group checkboxes">
                                <label class="form-control-label"><?php echo $records['question']; ?></label>
                                <div>
                                    <?php 
                                        $opt = explode("::", $records['options']);
                                        $result = count($opt);
                                        $i="1"; 
                                        foreach($opt as $s)
                                            {
                                        ?>
                                                <label class="form-container"><?php echo $s; ?>
                                                <input class="all-mandatory-check" type="checkbox" attr-required="<?php echo $records['mandatory']; ?>" id="name" value='<?php echo $s; ?>'  name='check_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>[]'>
                                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                                </label>
                                        <?php }  ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php
                        }   
                            $key;
                            if($key!="0"){
                    ?>
                    
                    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" /> 
                            <?php } ?>
                <?php
                $record_last_end = $rec;
                $lastElement = array_key_last($record_last_end);
                if($key == $lastElement)
                { 
                
                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="next action-button" >  
                <?php } else { ?>   
                
                <input type="button" name="next" id="next1" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                    <?php }  ?> 
                
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php 
                        //$i++;
                        } ?>
                
                
                </form>
```

Comment: Just disable the next button, until the input conditions meet your need

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you want to validate this using PHP, or using JS?